# Map putAll overrides or adds?

Tags: java, dictionary

When i use the `.putAll()` will another `.putAll()` override the content of the map?
Will my map contain SomeOfMyObjects and SomeOfMyObjects?

```
Map<MyObject> blah = new HashMap<>();
blah.putAll('SomeOfMyObjects')
blah.putAll('SomeOfMyObjects')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try it and you'll know. That would be better than any possible answer.

Comment: True, i need to cover it in my tests!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[If you see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-)

> Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map (optional operation). The effect of this call is equivalent to that of calling put(k, v) on this map once for each mapping from key k to value v in the specified map.

```
this call is equivalent to that of calling put(k, v)
```

And for  [as per put() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, **the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

Comment: "So it never overrides..." But the doc you quoted says, "the old value is replaced by the specified value." So it *does* override.

Answer (score 10):

It behaves just like calling `put(k,v)` for every entry in the argument map, so it adds, retaining whatever is already in the map. If the same key `k` is added again, its value `v` is overwritten. `putAll()` tries to optimize the bulk-add by first expanding the map internally to accommodate the new data, as to avoid intermediate resizing/rehashing operations.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone else finds the advice above opposing. But as a new Jenkins/Groovy user, I had to test it for myself to validate and can confirm it overwrites for "put" and "putAll".

```
        LinkedHashMap test = [X: 1]
        test.put("X", 2)
        assertTrue(test["X"] == 2)
```

and

```
        LinkedHashMap test = [X: 1]
        LinkedHashMap test2 = [X: 2]
        test.putAll(test2)
        assertTrue(test["X"] == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) it just adds the maps, and does not override the content:

> The effect of this call is equivalent to that of calling put(k, v) on this map once for each mapping from key k to value v in the specified map

And in `put(k,v)`:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

So with this definition, it **overrides** existing keys with new values.

Comment: Doesn't say that at all, unless the documentation has changed

Comment: Since my comment was from 2013, I don't remember what it said at that time. But if you read, it says:
The effect of this call is equivalent to that of calling put(k, v) on this map once for each mapping from key k to value v in the specified map.
And if you go to put:
If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value

Comment: Whether the documentation changed or not, `putAll` will `put` All. This behaviour hasn't changed, even if documentation was reworded between then and now.